# FBSession returns FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed after one successful login

Tags: ios7, facebook-ios-sdk

I have integrated about a month ago the **Facebook SDK for iOS** in my application and it was working as expected. About couple of days ago I noticed that after the first login **FBSession** was always **FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed**.

I have implemented all methods in AppDelegate and tested the app according to the tutorials of Facebook.

I am currently using Facebook SDK 3.15.1 and I have tried with 3.17 with the same results.

If I remove my application from my Facebook account and try to login the login would be successful but if I log out and try to login again then the problem appears again.

Do you have any ideas? Has anyone faced the same problem?

Something I forgot to mention is that this problem occurs only on physical devices and not the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the bundle ID of my facebook app. The weird thing is that for two months worked as expected but after that the problem appeared.